# HTML <img src> wont load my images

Tags: html, image, src

Im at a loss with this, im creating a mobile version of my website with jquery, but my images are refusing to load with img src tag.

```
<img src="images/me.jpg" width="200" height="267" alt="me">
```

ive tried using  to load my image straight from my website but they're refusing to load also, and moving the image to the same directory as the web page, but still nothing. I just get a box the size of the width and height with the alt text and an image icon in the middle.

I just don't understand whats wrong with it.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the `me.jpg` image is in the `images` directory and that the web server has permissions to access that directory and that it is configured to server up images from it?

Comment: the images are definitely in the right directory. I've tried to fix it locally rather than online, and im still getting the same problem

Comment: You should get `404 not found` error, if you are trying to load them from wrong directory, or `403 unauthorized` if your application does not have permissions to access the dicrectory. Check your console for errors.

Comment: Check your HTML then - are you sure it is in the correct directory? Have you saved your changes? Are you using server side includes or the like that may cause confusion regarding the actual path?

Comment: right ok I downloaded the source files from my full website, where everything is working fine. ran the website locally the same problem, this web page is literally just html and css.

Comment: you can try 2 things 
1: enter the full path of image in src
2: save the image, open in Photoshop and save it again as JPG.. and try it...

Comment: Thanks for the help found the problem, there was a problem with my images they wouldn't open in photoshop or paint or anything else, so i've just found my original images and replaced them. thanks for they help, so now the images are working as they should

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My images were in fact corrupt or not working properly as I couldn't open them in Photoshop, I had to replace the images.

Answer (score 8):

Try to work with the full path as:

`<img src="http://www.yourdomain.com/images/me.jpg" width="200" height="267" alt="me">`

For test purpose just open http://www.yourdomain.com/images/me.jpg and you should see the image. If it does not work, there must be a compatibility issue with your html/jquery. Just post the rest of your html file and tell us about the jquery plugin(s) you are using ...

Comment: try this...

if your index.html or index.php is in folder /yourdomain and your image is contained in /yourdomain/image , modify src="./image/<your_image_filename>"

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the suggestions very much appreciated. There was a problem with the images, the files must've been corrupt or something as they weren't opening in anything. So i've simply replaced the images.

Comment: You don't have to put the whole domain... you can just use `/images/me.jpg`

Answer (score 3):

**instead of using this syntax**

```
<img src="images/me.jpg" width="200" height="267" alt="me">
```

**please use like this**

```
import img1 from '../images/me.jpg';
<img src={img1} width="200" height="267" alt="me">
```

it will definitely work

Comment: This saved my life, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have just had the same issue. It was capital letters in the filename. Some pictures were loading some weren't. Some pictures had uppercase `.JPG` file extension, and some had lowercase `.jpg`. My HTML code referenced all of the images using lowercase `.jpg`.

I'm running webserver on my Synology DS.

Answer (score 1):

I just started writing html last night so this is a total noob response because i just had the same problem, but if youre on a windows computer then your slashes in the file location should be back slashes instead of forward slashes
like i said- total noob but hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are in the right subdomain in case you are using dev, staging etc.

I was wondering too, until I figured out that I am on the staging domain where the image does not exist.

Also make sure to clear the cache.

Answer (score 0):

If you try different things and it doesn't work, just move your image file to your working folder where your HTML file is.

The following works:

```html
<img src="me.jpg" width="200" height="267" alt="me">
```

Answer (score 0):

Be aware if you are using thymeleaf. Then you must have source like: (It by itself go through and do not take repository paths,...).

```
<div id="upperPart">
    <img id="foxPicture" th:src="greenfox.png" height="200" width="200" alt="Green Fox logo"/>
    <a class="Mr.Fox_description">This is Mr. Fox. Currently living on pizza and lemonade. He knows 2 tricks. </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One other possible cause is your server has a bug which has crashed it. When that happens, it will show the same error.

If your server auto-restarts on crashes, it can be difficult to reproduce this bug to fix it.

This happened to me while using PM2 with NodeJS.

Answer (score -1):

- List item

  1. Just go the image location on your drive
  2. select the image
  3. open it using your favourite browser
  4. go to url bar
  5. copy the location from the url bar
  6. use it in img src=(paste over here)
  7. It will look something like this
  8. img src="file:///C:/Users/Mercy/Documents/WEB%20DEVELOPMENT/HTML5/lion.jpg" alt="Lion profile picture" height="300" width="500"

Answer (score -2):

I've solved my problem by replacing `src="image.jpg"` with `src="file:///c:\FULL_PATH\image.jpg"`